# How to convert current datetime into given timezone and store in MongoDB & fetch in DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm format?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timezone, moment-timezone

My local time is `'Asia/Kolkata.'`
And I have to convert the current DateTime into `'Pacific/Auckland'` and store it into MongoDB

And on fetch I have to format this date into `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm`

Comment: Not possible. Dates in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - **always and only**. Usually the client application is responsible to **display** the date/time in local time zone and local format.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I have to store date timezone wise. For example, My localtime is 2022-05-13T13:30:00 and timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata' And I have convert this time to new zealand time and zone is ''Pacific/Auckland'. After convert store into MongoDB's Date format and on fetch data I have to format this date in DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm format.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
To store into the database, I prefer storing in UTC mode.
In case you need to convert your time into some other timezone's time, Have a look at it here.

```
date = new Date();
timeZone = 'Pacific/Auckland';

timestamp = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone })
```

Hope this works!

Comment: What happened when I fetch date and format in DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm

Comment: `timeZone = 'Pacific/Auckland';`  Where can I find such syntax for Los Angeles, or London?